# The DataAnnotations [Phone] Attribute

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc, validation, data-annotations

What is the default, valid format of the [Phone] attribute? 
In the data table, the phone column is navrchar (16)
If I enter a phone # like 1112223333, I get "field is not a valid phone number." 
If I enter 01112223333, I get "The value '11112223333' is invalid."

Also, how to override it?
I understand that I could do something like this, but is this the best practice in this case?

```
[RegularExpression(@"((\(\d{3}\) ?)|(\d{3}-))?\d{3}-\d{4}",ErrorMessage="Invalid Phone Number!")]
```

Related code:

```
    [Required]
    [Phone]
    public string Phone { get; set; }

    <div class="editor-field">
       @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Phone)
       @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Phone)
    </div>
```

**Update**
I guess there was a mapping issue when I changed the phone column from int to navrchar. Updating the model was not enough, so I had to change the value manually using the Table Mapping.

> Error 2019: Member Mapping specified is not valid. 
>   The type 'Edm.Int32[Nullable=False,DefaultValue=]' of member 'Phone' 
>   in type 'UserDBModel.UserProfile' is not compatible with 
>   'SqlServerCe.nvarchar[Nullable=False,DefaultValue=,MaxLength=16,Unicode=True,FixedLength=False]' 
>   of member 'Phone' in type 'UserDBModel.Store.UserProfile'.

Comment: This is a good practice. If you need to use the phone validation multiple times than better create your own ValidationAttribute (PhoneNumberAttribute).

Comment: You changed your column in the DB to 'nvarchar' but left the `Phone` property in `UserDBModel.UserProfile` an `int`

Answer (score 19):

The default regular expression for the `PhoneAttribute` can now be handily found by browsing the source code with [**.NET Reference Source** (*.NET Framework 2.7.2*)](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations/DataAnnotations/PhoneAttribute.cs) or [**source.dot.net** (*.NET Core*)](https://source.dot.net/#System.ComponentModel.Annotations/System/ComponentModel/DataAnnotations/PhoneAttribute.cs)

There it shows the (ugly) Regex as being defined as:

```cs
private static Regex _regex = new Regex(@"^(\+\s?)?((?<!\+.*)\(\+?\d+([\s\-\.]?\d+)?\)|\d+)([\s\-\.]?(\(\d+([\s\-\.]?\d+)?\)|\d+))*(\s?(x|ext\.?)\s?\d+)?$", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture);
```

That answers your direct question, but whether it helps or not remains to be seen. Maybe it would be a good base to create your own modified phone number regex.

[image: Sample Regex Matches]

Comment: What would be a sample number for that regex? I can't recreate it from the regex.

Comment: Careful with the regular expression. the negative look behind in the expression is not supported by all  browsers, especially IE

Answer (score 12):

Try this -

```
  [Required(ErrorMessage = "Mobile no. is required")]
  [RegularExpression("^(?!0+$)(\\+\\d{1,3}[- ]?)?(?!0+$)\\d{10,15}$", ErrorMessage = "Please enter valid phone no.")]
  public string Phone { get; set; }
```